# Find an equation of the tangent line to the curve $y^2= x^3(2-x)$ at the point $(1, 1)$.

Tags: calculus

I have to find an equation of the tangent line to the curve at the point $(1,1)$ for the equation $ y^2= x^3(2-x)$.

THANKS!

Comment: $T: y=f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)$

Comment: I know that, but I do not really know how to apply that. :/

Comment: You should include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, the slope of the tangent to the curve: $y^2=x^3(2-x)$ is given by differentiating w.r.t. $x$ as follows 
$$\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)=\frac{d}{dx}(x^3(2-x))$$
 $$2y\frac{dy}{dx}=x^3(-1)+3x^2(2-x)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6x^2-4x^3}{2y}$$
hence the equation of the tangent at the point $(1, 1)$ $$y-1=\left[\frac{dy}{dx}\right]_{(1, 1)}(x-1)$$

$$y-1=\left[\frac{6(1)^2-4(1)^3}{2(1)}\right](x-1)$$
$$y=x$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Differentiating
$$y^2 = {x^3}(2 - x)$$
with respect to $x$ gives you
$$2y\frac{dy}{dx} = {3x^2}(2 - x) - {x^3} = -4x^3 + 6x^2,$$
so that
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-4x^3 + 6x^2}{2y} = \frac{-2x^3 + 3x^2}{{x^{3/2}}\sqrt{2-x}} = \frac{-2x^2 + 3x}{\sqrt{x(2 - x)}}.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: In the last line, there was no need to substitute $y$.  Because we have to find the tangent at $x = 1, y = 1$, so the slope is required at that point